# Alternative versions

Tags: chess-variants

Are alternative chess rules/styles considered favourably by the main chess community? To be more specific I mean games like 3D chess (as seen in Star Trek) or landscape chess, as explained here:
http://intrepidis.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/landscape-chess.html

Are there tournaments for chess variants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only variants I can think of that experienced chess players seem to have any interest in are [Chess960](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess960) (aka Fischerandom) and [Bughouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bughouse_chess). Even [Seirawan chess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seirawan_chess), which has the imprimatur of a grandmaster, has not really attracted any real interest.

Other variants are not looked on unfavorably but they are basically ignored.

Comment: Bughouse sounds fun. I'll have to try that, thanks.

Comment: Don't forget crazyhouse!

Comment: @intrepidis: For Bughouse, [this rule-set](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/38910/9192) ensures progress (i.e. stalling is not possible) even in the absence of time controls. Incidentally, I also like Crazyhouse, which Travis suggested, because of the much bigger branching factor.

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of any regular tournaments for any chess variant with the exception of Chess960.